# Number of digits on Z3 Solver

Tags: integer, z3, z3py

Can I specify the number of digits in Int on the Z3py solver?
for example, X > 1 but X  has 3 digits ( 111 > 1) Can I determine the number of digits that model will return?

In other words:
I want to generate number based on the length I given. for example, I given length = 3, I want the solver to generate number with 3 digits

Comment: Why not just say `And(X >=100, x < 1000)`, which would guarantee 3 non-zero starting digits?

Comment: No, I want to generate number based on the length I given. for example, I given length = 3, I want the solver to generate number with 3 digits

Comment: Is the number of digits a constant or symbolic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you constrain `X` to be in a particular range, based on the desired length.  If you want `X` to have `L` digits, use

```
And(X >= 10**(L-1), X < 10**L)
```

I expect this to work better than converting to a string and then trying to apply a constraint to the string.

Comment: Exponentiation with a symbolic value will give rise to a non-linear constraint. It's worth trying out, but I'd expect this to be rather difficult for z3 to handle. (Of course, the same can also be said for `IntToStr`, though I'd expect that particular method to have built-in heuristics to help out.) In either case, experimenting with both encodings is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Length` and `IntToStr` methods:

```py
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
l = Int('l')

s = Solver()
s.add(Length(IntToStr(x)) == l)

# make it interesting
s.add(l > 3)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[x = 1400, l = 4]
```

Note that the `IntToStr` method is unlikely to work well (i.e., you might get unknown or might be too long to compute) if the constraints on the integer and the length is complicated. If length is a fixed constant, it should perform well.